# Why does spark-shell --master yarn-client fail (yet pyspark --master yarn seems to work)?

Tags: hdfs, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I'm trying to run the spark shell on my Hadoop cluster via Yarn.
I use

- Hadoop 2.4.1
- Spark 1.0.0

My Hadoop cluster already works. In order to use Spark, I built Spark as described [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-with-maven.html) :

```
mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.4 -Dhadoop.version=2.4.1 -DskipTests clean package
```

The compilation works fine, and I can run `spark-shell` without troubles. However, running it on yarn :

```
spark-shell --master yarn-client
```

gets me the following error :

```
14/07/07 11:30:32 INFO cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Application report from ASM:
         appMasterRpcPort: -1
         appStartTime: 1404725422955
         yarnAppState: ACCEPTED

14/07/07 11:30:33 INFO cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Application report from ASM:
         appMasterRpcPort: -1
         appStartTime: 1404725422955
         yarnAppState: FAILED

org.apache.spark.SparkException: Yarn application already ended,might be killed or not able to launch application master
.
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.waitForApp(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:105
)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.start(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:82)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:136)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:318)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.createSparkContext(SparkILoop.scala:957)
        at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:8)
        at $iwC.<init>(<console>:14)
        at <init>(<console>:16)
        at .<init>(<console>:20)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at .<init>(<console>:7)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at $print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:788)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1056)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:614)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:645)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:609)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:796)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:841)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:753)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoopInit.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoopInit.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.beQuietDuring(SparkIMain.scala:263)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.initializeSpark(SparkILoopInit.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$5.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:913)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.runThunks(SparkILoopInit.scala:142)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.runThunks(SparkILoop.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.postInitialization(SparkILoopInit.scala:104)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.postInitialization(SparkILoop.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:930)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:884)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:884)
        at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:884)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:982)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.launch(SparkSubmit.scala:292)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:55)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Spark manages to communicate with my cluster, but it doesn't work out.
Another interesting thing is that I can access my cluster using `pyspark --master yarn`. However, I get the following warning

```
14/07/07 14:10:11 WARN cluster.YarnClientClusterScheduler: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient memory
```

and an infinite computation time when doing something as simple as

```
sc.wholeTextFiles('hdfs://vm7x64.fr/').collect()
```

What may be causing this problem ?

Comment: The first error means Spark failed to start in the Yarn cluster; check you application's log (using `yarn logs`). The second means the cluster doesn't have enough resources to allocate your requested containers. Check your Yarn configuration to make sure it has enough memory available for containers.

Comment: @fxm, did you manage to make it work eventually? Does spark-shell even support YARN mode?

Answer (score 6):

Please check does your Hadoop cluster is running correctly.
On the master node next YARN process must be running:

```
$ jps
24970 ResourceManager
```

On slave nodes/executors:

```
$ jps
14389 NodeManager
```

Also make sure that you created a reference (or copied those files) to Hadoop configuration in Spark config directory :

```
$ ll /spark/conf/ | grep site
lrwxrwxrwx  1 hadoop hadoop   33 Jun  8 18:13 core-site.xml -> /hadoop/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml
lrwxrwxrwx  1 hadoop hadoop   33 Jun  8 18:13 hdfs-site.xml -> /hadoop/etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml
```

You also can check ResourceManager Web UI on port 8088 - http://master:8088/cluster/nodes. There must be a list of available nodes and resources.

You must take a look at your log files using next command (application ID you can find in Web UI):

```
$ yarn logs -applicationId <yourApplicationId>
```

Or you can look directly to entire log files on Master/ResourceManager host:

```
$ ll /hadoop/logs/ | grep resourcemanager
-rw-rw-r--  1 hadoop hadoop  368414 Jun 12 18:12 yarn-hadoop-resourcemanager-master.log
-rw-rw-r--  1 hadoop hadoop    2632 Jun 12 17:52 yarn-hadoop-resourcemanager-master.out
```

And on Slave/NodeManager hosts:

```
$ ll /hadoop/logs/ | grep nodemanager
-rw-rw-r--  1 hadoop hadoop  284134 Jun 12 18:12 yarn-hadoop-nodemanager-slave.log
-rw-rw-r--  1 hadoop hadoop     702 Jun  9 14:47 yarn-hadoop-nodemanager-slave.out
```

Also check if all environment variables are correct:

```
HADOOP_CONF_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=/hadoop/lib/native
HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/hadoop
HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=/hadoop
HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=/hadoop
YARN_HOME=/hadoop
HADOOP_INSTALL=/hadoop
HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/hadoop/etc/hadoop
YARN_CONF_DIR=/hadoop/etc/hadoop
SPARK_HOME=/spark
```

Comment: I'm unable to find where logs files are generated, I'll dig a little more

Comment: Try: `find /* -name "*yarn*log*"`

Comment: i am having same problem, i tried all of this but still problem is not solving. please if anyone help, i am stuck here.